# While installing react it gets stuck in between

Tags: javascript, reactjs, installation

[image]

While installing react only half gets installed, only my node modules gt installed after that it just hangs, src and public folder are not getting installed is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe install it not from VS Code, but directly from the terminal/command prompt.

```
npx create-react-app -name-
```

Comment: I dont understand so what am I supposed to do ?

Comment: @SushmithaKumaravel https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/install-react-with-create-react-app/

Comment: I have error while installing its getting stuck I have done all these steps and after that its getting stuck

Comment: I advise reinstalling Node js completely. Go to the control panel of Windows and then uninstall it and go to here to download and install it again: https://nodejs.org/en/